# LTspice gives wrong AC analysis

Tags: ltspice

I have multiple issues with LTspice. Take this trivial example:

```
XU1 N002 N001 vcc 0 N001 N003 ADA4807
V1 vcc 0 5
V2 N002 0 PULSE(0 1 0 0 0 0.5m 1m) AC 1
R1 N003 vcc 1k
C1 out 0 1p
R2 out N001 1
;tran 2m
.ac dec 1 100 1000Meg
.lib ADI.lib
.backanno
.end
```

[image]

`tran` works fine:

[image]

But `ac` gives me bogus results - like -47 dB "gain":

[image]

Comment: What happens if you bias the input near mid-supply instead of at the negative rail? Are you sure the ADI library is all correct for LTSpice syntax (as opposed to PSpice, HSpice, ...)?

Comment: The AC source goes above and below ground, but U1 only has a positive supply. Try giving U1 a split supply or adding a DC offset of Vcc/2 to the AC source.

Comment: @vofa, the AC analysis is totally linearized, so if the circuit has gain at Vin = 0, the AC sim will show that gain. And ADA4807 is spec'ed for input CM below the negative rail...but maybe the simulation model is funky in that operating range?

Comment: The output is not linear within some saturation voltage from Supply rail shown in "tran" as around 40mV so what will the small signal analysis say if you bias the output into the linear range? Does the output go below ground too? j/k

Comment: If you got the ADA4807 model from the analog.com page for the part, notice it's a PSpice model, not LTSpice. It also includes some "Switch" components which are a likely source of incompatibility between PSpice and LTSpice.

Comment: You are having problems with the grounded (-) supply terminal.

Comment: @ThePhoton I wouldn't be surprised at all if the model is the problem. Some supplier models are really bad, unfortunately.

Comment: @vofa That would be true for ANYONE else. But Mike at Linear *works very hard* to make absolutely certain that Linear's own opamps work in LTspice well. There's even proprietary code added to it for still better results than normal. If it is a Linear Tech part and the model is included with LTspice, it's going to work.

Comment: Silly me - I actually stumbled already across this and forgot...

Comment: Remember that both the input and output must be in linear range

Comment: @jonk you know mike?

Comment: @jonk, this is an AD part, and the model may predate the LT acquisition. (and the model available from analog.com is commented to say it's tested in PSpice, not LTSpice)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Kind of. He's been some good, personal help to me over the past 15 years. We've talked off and on. That's all.

Comment: @ThePhoton I suppose that's a possibility. But Mike takes these things very seriously. If he were allowed the time, he's probably made sure it works well. I'd put my bets on the model being "pretty good," though. But you do have a point.

Comment: @jonk, anyway even if the model is perfect, the follower circuit is not expected to work down to the rail---see my answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton Of course not!! I said as much in one of my comments. Just look above!

Comment: it must be a good model to attenuate the input and still have a transfer function when saturated

Comment: when in doubt view the error log >> Direct Newton iteration failed to find .op point.  (Use ".option noopiter" to skip.)

Comment: When people rush to blame the tools instead of checking against themselves, you know the vanity needs a bit trimming. This could have been a slip, an omission, it happens everywhere (I didn't downvote because of this), but to blame a tool that has been serving for well over 15 years, well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by just about everyone in the comments, your op amp doesn't work because your DC bias point is 0V and the op amp will only work for inputs between its rails (0V and 5V).

Your options are either:
1) Use positive and negative op amp rails, or
2) Bias the input AC voltage to between the two rails, e.g. 2.5VDC.

As seen below, with the DC bias point set at 0, I get similar broken behavior (although its a bit different since I used a different op amp)

[image]

If I add a 2.5V DC offset to the AC input, I get the expected behavior:

[image]

**EDIT**:  See also The Photon's answer describing why the minimum output voltage limits you in this case.

Comment: Does the behavior change at all if you add 1 milliohm ESR to V1 and V2?

Comment: You said "the op amp will only work for inputs between its rails (0V and 5V)" but this is not true for ADA4807. This part has allowed input common mode at 0.2 V below the negative rail (or above the positive rail).

Comment: @The Photon The datasheet uses the qualifier "−VS ≤ VICM ≤ +VS − 1.5 V" for all specs.  That is, your common mode input must be between the negative rail and 1.5V below the positive rail.  The "Absolute Max ratings" table says that the VICM can be 0.2V beyond the supply voltages, but this is just a survival limit - it does not guarantee that it will WORK at those voltages, just that it won't be damaged.

Comment: @Selvek, the line I'm referring to is the input common mode range line in the specifications, not the input voltage line in the maximum ratings. Performance might not meet the other specs with inputs outside the rails, but it should still act as an amplifier. In the Theory of Operation section it also says "The ADA4807-1/ADA4807-2/ADA4807-4 input operates 200 mV
beyond either rail."

Comment: @The Photon Oh ok didn't see that.  But operating in a region of the chip with unspecified performance is still a bad idea, and it's very likely the model accuracy will break down at those extremes.

Comment: @Selvek, true, but most "rail-to-rail" op-amps will have the same issue of no guaranteed specs near the rails.

Comment: @The Photon Yeah, which is why you should generally avoid using them there if you expect linearity.  But, if the amp were used in a different configuration where the inputs were slightly below the rail but the nominal output were between the two rails, it would work better than the voltage follower example.  So I gave you +1 and a shout out in my answer for pointing out the minimum output voltage impact.

Answer (score 7):

The ADA4807 input range includes the negative and positive rails. In fact it allows input 0.2 V beyond either rail.

[image]

Further, in the Theory of Operation section the datasheet says,

[image]

Specifications like input bias current, offset voltage, etc., might not be maintained with the input biased at the negative rail, but in general this op-amp should still act like an op-amp in that condition.

However, the minimum output voltage is 0.1 V above the negative rail. You'll also notice that the minimum output voltage in your transient simulation was about +0.1 V.

Therefore a follower configuration cannot maintain negative feedback when the input is at or below the rail, and the op-amp will be saturated at this bias point.

In saturation, very low AC gain is expected, and this is reflected in your AC simulation result.

If you arrange to have a negative supply available, or bias the input at least 0.1 V above the negative rail, you should see a gain of 1 for this circuit.

Answer (score 0):

For AC analysis, LTSpice constructs a linear (small signal) model of your circuit **considering the DC operating point** [*]. Datasheet of the device [ADA4807](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4807-1_4807-2_4807-4.pdf) says that this is a *rail to rail input/output* opamp, though the LTSpice model doesn't seem to agree with it. Especially the ground rail, transient output could not go below about 0.07V however it reaches 1V perfectly. Based on this, for the opamp **model** that cannot amplify at ground DC level, the AC simulation seems fine (i.e. in accordance with the transient output).

To resolve, you may add a DC bias to your AC signal source via its DC voltage property (should be at the upper right corner of the properties window of signal source V2).

A better and widely useful way of supplying such biasing conditions is as follows: You may AC couple your input signal via a large (1GF) capacitor, and provide your DC bias (like Vcc/2) via a large (1GH) inductor, as shown in the below figure:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftZhXH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[*] LTSpice uses DC operating point analysis to obtain those DC voltages at all nodes. In your circuit, AC analysis sees 0V-DC at the + input of the opamp since no other DC bias is applied, which supposedly prevents amplification.