# LTspice op-amp phase margin

Tags: operational-amplifier

I created an LTspice model of my circuit which consists of an op-amp in a unity gain voltage follower configuration which feeds a SAR ADC. I also included the flywheel circuit in front of the ADC. There are two models, each one having a different op-amp.

The one labeled "bad" uses a TI 4111 which isn't really designed to handle the capacitive load my circuit has.  I originally designed with this op-amp before I knew the capacitance values. Thus I made a second circuit that uses an op-amp with unlimited capacitance drive.

Using the analog suggestion on how to measure phase margin I plotted the following.

Not sure how to interpret these, it seems that the TLV4111 has more phase margin than the analog ADA4807 which seems backwards to me given the load circuit. Any suggestions?

[image]

Updated the picture with the suggestion of adding a DC source on the + input; it doesn't seem to have made a difference:

[image]

Comment: Regarding sources V1, V2 and V4 and the use of the switch in AC analysis: do read my answer in [How to implement AC analysis in a resonant circuit in LTspice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/431546/how-to-implement-ac-analysis-in-a-resonant-circuit-in-ltspice/431566#431566).

Comment: What are you actually trying to test? Why are you injecting noise in the feedback loop of the opamp? This way you're not simulation *"an op amp in a unity gain voltage follower configuration"*.

Comment: I'm digitize an old analog vehicle sensor that provides a voltage to the cars ecu.  Recently I realized that the ecu has front end circuitry that results in a large capacitive load to my circuit.  it was obvious from the op amp datasheet I was using would be unable to drive this load.  I want to analyze this.  Here is some details on my design. http://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers/f/14/p/839923/3121607#3121607.                                         Ignore the current draw of 100 mA turns out that was a bad measurement, the output draws wmA ish.

Comment: Regarding injecting noise, I'm not sure what you mean. I setup the model per this analog video.  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=%23&ved=2ahUKEwjJwbqYuP3kAhXxnuAKHdN1CygQwqsBMAB6BAgFEAQ&usg=AOvVaw0VTJzWxrN8ZFOD4xbU2nov

Comment: Link doesn't work...

Comment: https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/videos/5579254320001.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I learnt something new! In the video, they insert a voltage source with **DC value** of **0V** and AC amplitude of 1V. In your simulation you used a DC value of 2.5V. What is the motivation to do so?

Comment: Started with a DC of 0 but got very odd results, gain started at like -65db.... Read a thread on Here that said since I'm powering the op amp 5vdc that I needed to bump the voltage input to be in between the rails.   https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355175/ltspice-gives-wrong-ac-analysis

Comment: Ill try to get the same simulation tomorrow when on PC again. Could yo share (a link) of the implementation of TI 4111?

Comment: TLV4111 model: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16f1DOy9MGa5eAqLpUB9AkA7d-5P2t6DK            TLV4111 ac analysis:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yB7cSt02a8esAloV1XLMuPj0H3VwHI5K     ADA4807 AC analysis:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XzN9bI2dqWq7XrIicgfRNYllvPiZDeZM

Comment: If the "capacitive load" you're referring to is the 33nF cap, then it shouldn't affect the phase margin because it's isolated from the op amp's output by the 6k8 resistor.

Answer (score 1):

> Read a thread on [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355175/ltspice-gives-wrong-ac-analysis) that said since I'm powering the op amp 5vdc that I needed to bump the voltage input to be in between the rails.

Citation from that answer:

> As mentioned by just about everyone in the comments, your op amp doesn't work because your DC bias point is 0V and the op amp will only work for inputs between its rails (0V and 5V).

Because you use the opamp in a unity gain voltage follower configuration, the **input** of your opamp is the **positive** input terminal of the opamp.
To prevent the operating point running into the power rails, you should not short this positive input terminal of the opamp to GND, because that causes an operation point of 0V. Instead, insert a voltage source (e.g.) 2.5Vdc on it (source V5 with value {Vin} as shown below). The AC source should have an DC component that is 0Vdc.

You can verify this by stepping the voltage of this DC voltage source V5 with `.step param Vin LIST 1V 2V 3V` : they should yield the same outputs for AC transient analysis.

[image]

Comment: You are indeed correct. Sorry about that.

Comment: OP is doing a AC transient while the operation point is clipping. Maybe I should start with that... and I'll attach an LTSpice scteenshot showing where to add this DC source (when on PC again)

Comment: Did the update, see the original post... Didn't seem to make a difference, did i miss something?